# What is the yellow runny stuff Rose keeps making in a wood box in "Slow West"?

Tags: plot-explanation

In the movie [*Slow West*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slow_West) there is a scene where Rose serves a yellow runny viscous stuff as food. The same stuff occurs again at the end of the movie. Having tried various keywords I can't seem to find a clip or a screenshot online, let alone identify it. I took a shot.

[image]

She lifts the lid of the box and opens it up by pushing the sides apart, and the viscous stuff spills out. Her father then comments: "An improvement, it stays on the table." Is it a cheese? Her family is from Scotland. And the movie is set in the late 19th century.

Comment: I definitely assumed it was butter, early made butter was difficult to keep as we now expect it to be. I'm also pretty sure I've seen it or something like it in my past -

Comment: I made butter using a glass jar when I was a kid, and am confused about the butter "not setting." It doesn't set because after churning, it is a solid already. I see the script mentions setting, but this isn't a step in the process of making butter. Also, you'd press the butter in the mold like play dough or clay, so melting it isn't something one would do either. Very odd.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [script](https://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/SlowWestScript.pdf) it’s butter that has not set (from a "butter mold").

> Slow track towards the kitchen table - ROSE brings the butter mold to
> the table, as the two SWEDISH KIDS (from the trading post, then
> Payne’s gang) play by the table ROSE lifts the lid of the butter, but
> it still has not set and flows onto the table

Comment: Since your link was to a fan-written version of the script, I've taken the liberty of linking to a legit script and adding a quote.